# R: Why train() function in caret returns null model (Call: NULL)?

Tags: r, r-caret

For example, I use train to build a logistic regression like below:

```
library(caret)

n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(x1=runif(n, min=0, max=1),
                 x2=runif(n, min=0, max=1),
                 y = rep(c('N', 'Y'), n/2)[sample(n, n)])
lmFit <- train(y ~ ., data=df, method='glm', family = binomial)
summary(lmFit)
```

It will display

```
Call:
NULL    
....
```

Is there a setting to make it display the correct `glm` call, instead of `NULL`?
Thank you.

Comment: it will be good if you can provide us reproducible example dput()

Comment: @Hunaidkhan, I edited with an example code

Comment: Thanks but it is working fine in my environment.not getting any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see such a setting to supply to summary, since the summary.train method strips the call value:

```
> class(lmFit)
[1] "train"         "train.formula"
> getAnywhere(summary.train)
A single object matching ‘summary.train’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for summary from namespace caret
  namespace:caret
with value

function (object, ...) 
summary(object$finalModel, ...)
<bytecode: 0x1bc4f820>
<environment: namespace:caret>

> names(lmFit)
 [1] "method"       "modelInfo"    "modelType"    "results"      "pred"         "bestTune"     "call"        
 [8] "dots"         "metric"       "control"      "finalModel"   "preProcess"   "trainingData" "resample"    
[15] "resampledCM"  "perfNames"    "maximize"     "yLimits"      "times"        "levels"       "terms"       
[22] "coefnames"    "xlevels"
```

You could make a variant of that function that either outputs the call using `cat`, or returns it as part of the `summary` object, or both. Or you could just add this to your script:

```
> lmFit$call
train.formula(form = y ~ ., data = df, method = "glm", family = binomial)
```

Comment: It does this because, depending on how you invoke `train`, the entire training set can get embedded into the call object.

Comment: It would seem less confusing to users if you would have `summary.train` suppress the header `"Call:\nNULL"`. It might be less likely that users would think something was missing that should have been done differently.